# Shiny -- Record the last actionButton pressed and renderPlot accordingly

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny question which I think involves JS but my knowledge on JS is non-existent. I want to be able to print only one the boxplot from below depending on the actionButton pressed in the same panel. I dont really know if I need to do this in this way so any help is appreciated. Here is a summarized version of my code.

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  data_for_use <- reactiveValues(d=NULL) 

  observe({
    input$DownloadButton
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'testmessage',
                              message = list(a = "A"))
  })
  observe({
    input$UploadButton
    session$sendCustomMessage(type = 'testmessage',
                              message = list(a = "B"))
  })

  observeEvent(input$DownloadButton, {
      GSEmRNA <- data.frame(first=c(3,5,7), second=c(10,11,54), third=c(26,12,5)) 
      data_for_use$d <- GSEmRNA
  })

  observeEvent(input$UploadButton,{
        GSEmRNA <- data.frame(first=c(1,6,9), second=c(5,5,5), third=c(17,6,18))
      data_for_use$d <- GSEmRNA
  })
  output$BoxplotDatasetDownload <- renderPlot({
    if (input$DownloadButton== 0) {return()}       
    else{
      boxplot(data_for_use$d)}
  })
  output$BoxplotDatasetUpload <- renderPlot({
    if (input$UploadButton== 0) {return()}       
    else{
      boxplot(data_for_use$d)}
  })
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Dataset Selection"),
# Sidebar with controls to select a dataset and specify the number
# of observations to view
sidebarPanel(
  actionButton("DownloadButton","Download"),
  actionButton("UploadButton","Upload"),

  tabPanel(
    tags$head(tags$script('Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("testmessage",
  function(message) {
    print("The a variable is " + message.a);
  }
);')))

),
mainPanel(
  conditionalPanel(condition="input.DownloadButton && message.a == 'A'",
  wellPanel(
    column(8, plotOutput("BoxplotDatasetDownload")
  )
)),
conditionalPanel(condition="input.UploadButton && message.a == 'B'",
  wellPanel(
    column(8, plotOutput("BoxplotDatasetUpload"))
  ))

)))
```

EDIT : I tried something like this which should have worked I guess but it doesnt. In ui.R I added

```
conditionalPanel(condition= "input.DownloadButton && input.UploadButton",
                     radioButtons("checkboxUpDown", label=h3("Choose which results to show"),
                                  choices = list('Uploaded Data', 'Downloaded Data'), selected = NULL))

wellPanel("Input",
                                   fluidRow(
                                     conditionalPanel(condition= "input.UploadButton && !input.DownloadButton",
                                                      column(8, DT::dataTableOutput("dataTableUpload")
                                                      ))),
                                   fluidRow(
                                     conditionalPanel(condition= "input.DownloadButton&& !input.UploadButton",
                                                      column(8,DT::dataTableOutput("dataTableDownload")))
                                   ),fluidRow(
                                     conditionalPanel(condition= "input.DownloadButton&& input.UploadButton",
                                                      conditionalPanel(condition= "input.checkboxUpDown == 'Uploaded Data'",
                                                      column(8,DT::dataTableOutput("dataTableUpload"))),
                                                      conditionalPanel(condition= "input.checkboxUpDown == 'Downloaded Data'",
                                                                       column(8,DT::dataTableOutput("dataTableDownload"))))
                                   ))
```

Comment: What you're trying to do (using a conditional panel with a condition that's decided in the server) is weird and isn't generally done, mostly because there isn't a nice way to do it.  You should look into the `shinyjs` package, it has a `show()` and `hide()` functions that you could use.

Comment: I tried shinyjs but couldnt manage it. I would love to see a pseudocode kinda thing to apply my code. .Instead I tried another way. Adding a radiobutton and having user select which plot to show by selecting the radiobuttons but that too doesnt work. Here is what I tried updated in the question...

Comment: you know what .. I actually could manage to do it with hide and show thanks a lot

Comment: Hey I saw you saying that you will be extremely busy but If you find time could you let me know if show() and hide() functions stopped working or not ? Thanks

Comment: There hasn't been an update in the package in a while since I don't have time to work on it now, so no, there should be no change